# how to disable copy/paste in textbox in windows phone using c#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I have one textbox in which i just want user to do an manual entry.so i need to disable copy and as-specially paste option which is there in windows phone. is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunaly not possible.

The only solution is to create your own control, with a custom keyboard too.

Regards,

Answer (score -4):

`Textbox` is not copy-paste-able. You can try using a `ReadOnly TextBox` as seen here: [WP7 CopyPaste on TextBox](http://sharpgis.net/post/2011/04/03/Windows-Phone-7-CopyPaste-on-TextBlocks.aspx)
.

You could also put it in a `WebBrowser` control (provided you have enough content and are willing to suffer the display / performance )

Comment: hi, my doubt is for textbox's text.i just want user not to copy and paste the text from one textbox to other.what can i do for that??

Comment: Your own link says "copy/paste only works on TextBoxes", so your statement "Textbox is not copy-paste-able" is wrong.